# How to store int value in the table column with comma seperated using asp.net mvc

Tags: linq-to-sql, database-design

I have a table called Comments. with each comment I have comment Id,.

on my user screen I can add more than One Comment to each user.. so that comment id needs to store for this use as 1,2,3,.. Etc.. that means I added 1 2 3 comment Ids for the user..

How to store those comma seperated values in to the table column?

Thanks

Comment: If this is intended to be extensible and used for the long haul don't do it this way. Create another table to map comments to users. Normalization is more work in the beginning but less work in the end.

Comment: Anytime you consider a comma delimited list, you need another related table. Data should never be stored as a comma delimted list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't.  Use a join table that has columns for UserID and CommentID to link the user with their comments.  Then you can get the set of comments for a user with a three-way join between the `User`, `UserComments`, and `Comments` tables.

```
select Comments.*
from Users inner join UserComments on Users.UserID == UserComments.UserID
           inner join Comments on UserComments.CommentID == Comments.CommentID
where Users.UserID == @userid
```

where @userid is the id of the user in question.

With LINQ you simply need to reference the proper entity sets and, probably, use `SelectMany`.

```
var comments = context.Users
                      .Where( u => u.UserID == userid )
                      .SelectMany( u => u.UserComments
                                         .SelectMany( uc => uc.Comments ) );
```